# CanJS: Model.findAll() vs new Model.List()

Tags: canjs

There seems to be a difference between

```
can.Component.extend({
  viewModel: {
    items: new Model.List(),
    updateItems: function(viewModel) {
      viewModel.attr('items', new Model.List({}));
   }
}
```

and

```
can.Component.extend({
  viewModel: {
    items: new Model.List(),
    updateItems: function(viewModel) {
      Model.findAll({}, function(items) {
        viewModel.attr('items', items);
      });
   }
}
```

in that the former triggers change events on items but the latter does not, please see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peterwimsey/26q7o69r/).

1. Could someone explain why? As far as I understand the docs both `new Model.List()` and `Model.findAll()` return a `can.Model.List`.
2. No event is triggered when the result is an empty list. Should this not trigger at least the `length` event?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, `Model.findAll()` returns a promise that resolves to a list.

The reason is that:

```
  Model.findAll({}, function(items) {
    viewModel.attr('items', items);
  });
```

Doesn't actually change 'items' length.  'items' is set to a list that already has a length, and that length never changes.  So no, "{items} length" doesn't callback when items or the length changes, only when the current 'items' length changes.

This is different than:

```
viewModel.attr('items', new Model.List({}));
```

Which sets 'items' to an initially empty list.  Later that list is updated with items, which changes the 'items' list's length property.

Comment: Thanks Justin, I think I understand the technical explanation. I would have expected change events when I listen to a model's field regardless of how that field got changed. What would be the recommended way of achieving this? Is there a better way of setting up events or should I call my own handler inside `findAll`s callback?

Comment: Computes via the define plugin are a better way of handing this. They are able to listen to a variety of values and only update once. I don't really listen to events in my CanJS apps.  Look at the MakeModelYear example:  http://canjs.com/docs/can.List.plugins.promise.html and this fiddle: http://jsbin.com/tehobu/4/edit?html,js,output

Comment: "I would have expected change events when I listen to a model's field regardless of how that field got changed." Say there was an object with properties like root.base.child.prop.  If you listen to child.prop, you shouldn't expect to be notified if root.base changes.  I don't think anything works this way.